# How to delete XML element with specific contents using PHP regexp?

Tags: php, regex

I need to delete the `offer` element with city Moscow in the following XML:

```
<offer id="14305" available="true">
<param name="City">Moscow</param>
</offer>
<offer id="14306" available="true">
<param name="City">LA</param>
</offer>
```

How can I do it with PHP regular expressions?

I tried:

```
preg_replace('/<offer[^(>Moscow<).]+?<\/offer>/s', ''. $string);
```

but without success.

I read your advices. It is really great. But I have a new problem with greedy:

```
<offer id="14305" available="true">
<param name="Color">Red</param>
<engine>XYZ</engine>
<param name="City">Moscow</param>
</offer>
<offer id="14306" available="true">
<param name="Color">Red</param>
<param name="City">LA</param>
</offer>
<offer id="14306" available="true">
<weight>1000</weight>
<param name="Color">Red</param>
<param name="City">LA</param>
</offer>
```

My regexp is too greedy :(

```
<offer.*?>\s*?<param.*?>\s*?Moscow\s*?<\/param>\s*?<\/offer>
```

Comment: Why not use php's xml functions to strip out the element, preg_replace is a lot more error-prone.

Comment: regex is not the tool to parse XML.

Comment: Yes. File is too big. I will use SimpleXML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this RegEx:

```
<offer.*?>\s*?<param.*?>\s*?Moscow\s*?<\/param>\s*?<\/offer>
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Regexr**](http://regexr.com/3d2n1)</kbd>

---

How it works:

```
<offer.*?>    # Select opening <offer> with optional parameters
\s*?          # Optional Whitespace
<param.*?>    # Select opening <param> with options parameters
\s*?          # Optional Whitespace
Moscow        # Select Moscow text
\s*?          # Optional Whitespace
<\/param>     # Select closing </param>
\s*?          # Optional Whitespace
<\/offer>     # Select closing </offer>
```

Comment: What about new lines and indentation?

Comment: @dotancohen You can just put \s* between each element to match any whitespace, no biggie.

Comment: @dotancohen I have updated it to work with newlines and indentation / whitespace, using `\n?\s*?` That should work, yes?

Comment: @Druzion: \s already matches newlines, so it's not necessary to put \n next to \s. You can just put \s* between your XML-elements and that will be enough. Your current solution won't match if there is trailing whitespace _before_ the newline.

Comment: @klaar I suspected so, thanks! I'll update the answer

Comment: Thanks, great! Good solvation.

Answer (score 0):

```
<offer[^>]*>[^<]*<param[^>]*>Moscow<\/param>[^<]*<\/offer>
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qK0hI6/1)

Comment: This won't work if the `offer`-XML-elements contain anything other than suspected in this pattern.

Comment: @klaar I didn't get what you mean

Comment: It will only match offer items that also and only contain param children items, but no other offer items that might contain other things. As Sebastiaan de Rooij said in a comment, it's better to let this be handled by a proper XML-parser instead of using regexp.